# Javascript + PHP: Remove extra fields during echo

Tags: javascript, php, dom

In the code below:

```
<SCRIPT> 
  var randomJS = Math.floor(Math.random()*11) 

  <?php
     $randomPHP = "<script>document.write(random)</script>"; 
  ?>

</SCRIPT>

<?php
     echo $randomPHP; 
?>
```

The php code will echo a random value in the webpage. This is all fine. But if I email it will echo the following:

```
<script>document.write(random)</script>
```

I don't want that. I just need a single numeric value.

Please let me know how to get this done?

Thank You.

UPDATE: 
Instead of email, lets assume I am trying to attach the random number in the link.

```
<form  class="form-inline" action="index.php#<?php echo $randomPHP ?>" method = "post" >

// Form code

</form>
```

This will output: I dont want that...

```
www.url/index.php#<script>document.write(random)</script>
```

I need this...

```
www.url/index.php#{-some-random-value-}
```

Comment: then show the email code bhai

Comment: PHP and JavaScript code do not run at the same time.

Comment: ok, you're outputting Javascript using PHP. Why? You can do a simple random number with either Javascript or with PHP. There's no reason to combine them like that. You're also declaring a Javascript variable for a random number and then using a different variable to write it. Also, Javascript will not work in an email. If you want it to work in email, you'll have to just use PHP. <?php echo rand(0, 11); ?>

Comment: Instead of email, lets assume I am trying to attach the random number in the link.

<form  class="form-inline" action="index.php#<?php echo $randomPHP ?>" method = "post" >

// Form code

</form>
This will output: I dont want that...

www.url/index.php#<script>document.write(random)</script>
I need this...

www.url/index.php#{-some-random-value-}

Comment: <form class="form-inline" action="index.php#<?php echo rand(0, 11) ?>" method = "post" >

Comment: @ShaneLessard This is good. But my value comes from JS. There is some computation and JS has the value like above. The code <script>document.write(random)</script> should pass a value to PHP variable. The PHP variable will then send the value via POST.

Comment: That wont work. The PHP renders before the page is loaded, Javascript loads after. You can't save the result of a javascript action to a PHP variable.What you're going to have to do is either do it in PHP or Javascript, stop trying to mix them.

Comment: What about getting the data after its rendered. Lets say second step. The data is loaded in browser. PHP gets that data and then pass it.?

Comment: PHP wont touch anything after the page is rendered. PHP is interpreted, the page is loaded, and then Javascript is interpreted.  By the time Javascript comes into play, PHP is already done it's job and gone to sleep. Try saving a variable in php like: $random = rand(0, 11);  and then echo that variable where you want that number to output. If you're doing it with Javascript, do it the same way you're doing it, without using PHP at all. Just save the random variable, and use document.write() to put it wherever you want. Either way, don't mix the languages this way, it's possible with either one

Answer (score 0):

```
<SCRIPT> 
  var randomJS = Math.floor(Math.random()*11) 

</SCRIPT>
```

and use `<script> document.write(randomJS);</script>` where you want to output the variable. The PHP you're using isn't helping anything, even if it does work.

Answer (score -1):

The code you provided has some errors. The random variable inside the document.write() javascript method is undefined. You can't reference a variable like that in php.

Here's the updated code.

```
<SCRIPT> 
  var randomJS = Math.floor(Math.random()*11) 

 <?php
   $randomPHP = "<script>document.write($randomJS)</script>"; 
  ?  >

</SCRIPT>

 <?php
 echo $randomPHP; 
  ?>
```

If you need a single random value use the php's  or Trim predefined functions

```
  substr();
```

see the substr documentation for more info    [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php98717601,d.c2E)